# Windows 10 cannot recognize Git

Tags: windows, git, ssh

I have installed Windows 10 x64 on my laptop, and then go with latest Git as well (`Git-2.6.3-64-bit`). As I see on my laptop, Git now is installed at this directory: `C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Git` (I have no chance to specify another particular folder because it's done automatically during Git installation). The options "**Use Git from the Windows Command Prompt**" and "**Use OpenSSH**" are already selected, the windows path is updated with Git dir. And after all, the problem is, Windows cannot recognize where Git is to call. I've tried `git --version` but it's unrecognized from Windows.

My questions are (on Windows 10 Pro x64):
 1. Can we specify another installation folder for Git?
 2. In Git dir/bin, there no ssh.exe, while in OpenSSH selection dialog, it tells me "This uses ssh.exe that comes with Git". So where is it, the built-tin SSH client?
 3. I'm doubting that now Windows 10 doesn't accept any external program installed on %USERPROFILE%/AppData to be included to system path. Is it correct?
 4. How to make Windows "see" Git?

Comment: make sure git.exe is in the folder you added to your path

Comment: I have the same problem after updating to git for windows 2.6.3 on Windows 10.  
```git``` got installed on ```C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Git``` instead of  
```C:\Program Files\Git```.<br>
The issue is that git still try to access stuff inside the ```C:\Program Files\Git``` folder:<br>  
        
<pre>
C:\projects\test>git clone https://github.com/foo/bar
Cloning into 'bar'...
fatal: unable to access 'github.com/foo/bar.git/';: error setting certificate
verify locations: 
   CAfile: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
   CApath: none
</pre>

Answer (score 1):

Just solved this myself this was a very frustrating journey but for me the following got me going:

1. Make sure c:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ is in your path variables (yea I know Windows should see this on its own)
2. Go to C:\Users\<>.gitconfig edit your global git config file to point to the correct ssh.exe 'C:/Windows/System32/OpenSSH
3. Make sure your id_rsa.ppk file is in C:\Users\<>.ssh If you don't have an SSH key yet generate one and make sure it ends up in this folder
4. You may also want to check that your OpenSSH Authentication Agent is started in Windows Services

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Can we specify another installation folder for Git?

Try running the installer as an administrator, so it can be installed to Program Files. I'm not sure how to specify a custom path.

> 2. In Git dir/bin, there no ssh.exe, while in OpenSSH selection dialog, it tells me "This uses ssh.exe that comes with Git". So where is it, the built-tin SSH client?

Some digging told me that it might live inside the `.ssh` folder in the Git installation, so `C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\.ssh`

> 3. I'm doubting that now Windows 10 doesn't accept any external program installed on %USERPROFILE%/AppData to be included to system path. Is it correct?

AFAIK you can add any directory to your path.

> 4. How to make Windows "see" Git?

Add `C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Git` to your path:

```
Start the System Control Panel applet (Start - Settings - Control Panel - System).
Select the Advanced tab.
Click the Environment Variables button.
Under System Variables, select Path, then click Edit.
You'll see a list of folders, as this example for my system shows: C:\Program Files\Windows Resource Kits\Tools\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Support Tools\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Ulead Systems\MPEG;C:\Program Files\Intel\DMIX;C:\Program Files\Executive Software\Diskeeper\;C:\Program Files\Bonjour\;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\Misc
You can add additional folders that you want to include in searches. I add a "C:\program files\misc" entry into which I place my standalone utilities, instead of copying them into C:\windows. Click OK.
You'll need to restart the processes (e.g., command prompt) that use the system path to see the added folders.
```

From http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/how-can-i-add-new-folder-my-system-path

Comment: Thanks @Pablo for your explanation. After inspecting the status in my laptop, I see that:  
1. There's no `.ssh` folder inside Git installation  
2. I've try to put some executable file to `%USERPROFILE%/AppData` and it still cannot be recognized by Windows  
3. I've added the Git path to System Variables but it still didn't work.

Comment: 1. "trying to install Git as administrator" doesn't solve the problem, I am affraid.